# Android horizontal + vertical scrolling control in android?

Tags: android, horizontal-scrolling, vertical-scrolling

I want same control like below in android

**https://github.com/Huanhoo/HHHorizontalPagingView**

Comment: I dont know why minus but atleast give reason and answer

Comment: Explain your question in detail.From this I understand that you want to create horizontally scrollable tabs and in each tab you want vertically scrollable content. Am I correct?

Comment: Check github link which i given i want same control like that .

Comment: Stackoverflow is not for such kind of descriptive answers. You can decompose your problem into small tasks and try to achieve that and then if you face any problems doing so then you can ask here. Do some google research and try yourself first.

Answer (score 0):

It's a combination of controls in android. you can use ViewPager to achieve horizontally scrollable view and RecyclerView to achieve vertically scrollable content.